# How to determine total value locked within a price range in Uniswap V3?

Tags: uniswap

Uniswap V3 front end shows you TVL for the entire range of prices of a pooled asset pair. But is it possible to calculate or determine total value locked within a specific range of prices? E.g. I'm interested in value locked for the pair token A/token B when the price of A (in terms of B) is between X and Y. With concentrated liquidity being one of the key features of V3, seems like this should be an easy query/calculation.